# Feather M0 doesn't show up as a COM or Serial port

Tags: arduino-ide, feather

I am trying to upload a simple blink program on my Adafruit Feather M0 Radio with LoRa Radio Module to ensure that it connects to my PC. So far, I have:

- Gone through 4 data cables
- Tested for connection on 3 different devices (laptop on Windows 11, desktop on Windows 10, and computer running CentOS respectively)
- Followed the direction for using the board with the IDE [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-radio-with-lora-radio-module/setup) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-radio-with-lora-radio-module/using-with-arduino-ide)

But the Port submenu is greyed out and when it isn't, it just doesn't have the port that recognizes my Feather. When going into Device Manager, I can't see it in the list of devices even when I refresh.

Comment: At some point did you double-tap reset?

Comment: Yes, many times. The problem persisted afterwards

Comment: Had it ever had anything uploaded to it successfully in the past? Is there anything connected it apart from the USB cable?

Comment: @timemage No, since I received my feather, I haven't had any success uploading anything to it

Comment: When you double-tap reset do you get the fade-in-fade-out indication on the pin13 LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the bootloader/USB firmware wasn't loaded in, which is why the double-tap reset wasn't working. I looked into the option of using another board as a programmer to get the bootloader in my Feather, but it proved to be more of a hassle than I thought so I'm just going to get a replacement. Hope this helps someone out in the future.